# Which algorithms are applied from Google Search until now 2016 year?

Tags: google-search, google-ranking, google-algorithm

So far we know that are announced Penguin and Panda as algorithms which had impact over the ranking on Google search engine.

What are the other algorithms that are applied so far until today June 2016 and what are their names?

I'm asking this because I heard rumors on forums that this year will be in force Panda 4.0.

They are applied in order also as version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 etc.

Comment: Asking for a list of Google algorithms is beyond the scope of this Q&A site.   Google launches algorithms daily and doesn't name most of them.